# Função exec() chama programa em segundo plano

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um gerenciador para meu Jogo online para que membros da equipe possa iniciar os emuladores.exe através do site, só que estou com um problema, os emuladores abre em segundo plano na maquina (VPS)

Então gostaria de saber se tem como fazer os emuladores execute normalmente, abrindo a janela do executável e não ficando em segundo plano.

```
<?php
if($_POST['emulador'] == "Ligar")
{
    exec("start D:\Servidor\Center\Gerenciador\ligar.bat");
    echo "<script>alert('Emulador Ativado!');</script>";
}
?>
```

Conteúdo do **ligar.bat**:

```
start /d "D:\Servidor 6.4\Servidor\Center" Center.Service.exe
@echo SERVIDOR FOI INICIADO ATRAVES DO SITE
@echo CMD IRA FECHAR EM 10 SEGUNDOS, AGUARDE E NAO INTERFIRA NO PROCESSO! 
timeout 10
```

---

Me apresentaram essa solução

```
if(!function_exists('pcntl_exec'))
{
    function pcntl_exec($path,$args=array())
    {
        if(is_string($args)) $args = array($args);
        if(count($args)) $path = sprintf('"%s"', $path);
        $shell = new COM('WScript.Shell');
        $shell->run($path.(count($args) ? ' '.implode(' ',$args) : ''),0,true);
    }
}
switch ($_POST['Center'])
{
    case "Ligar":
        pcntl_exec('D:\\Servidor\\Center\\Gerenciador\\ligar.bat');
        echo "<script>alert('Emulador Center Ativado!'); location.href='http://127.0.0.1/pt/?page=manager';</script>";
    break;
}
```

entretanto continua abrindo em segundo plano, alguma ideia ?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "primeiro plano"?

Comment: Lamento a forma de me expressar, quero apenas que ele abre como uma janela normal no servidor como esse cmd aqui http://prntscr.com/i1uyrx

Comment: Por favor edite  pergunta e adicione o conteúdo do seu .bat.

Comment: `Conteudo do bat : start /d "D:\Servidor 6.4\Servidor\Center" Center.Service.exe
@echo SERVIDOR FOI INICIADO ATRAVES DO SITE
@echo CMD IRA FECHAR EM 10 SEGUNDOS, AGUARDE E NAO INTERFIRA NO PROCESSO!
timeout 10`

Comment: tenta mudar o `start /d` por `cmd /c`