# Como coloco duas Datatable na mesma página?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-datatables

A primeira tabela pega certo porém a segunda não carrega fica a tabela sem os atributos da Datatable.
Como faço para utilizar as duas na mesma página?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui um exemplo basico de como fazer
para uma melhor utilização de todas as funçoes do datatable olhe aki:
https://datatables.net/examples/index
e para outros exemplos

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: [
          [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
          [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ]
        ],
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
    $('#example2').DataTable({
        data: [
          [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ]],
    });
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table id="example2" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: eu estou pegando os dados com um foreach php, tem como eu fazer com ele?

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo Existem varias formas de implementar isso 
o melhor seria vc ver as varias maneiras de preencher a tabela no link indicado e escolher a melhor maneira para o seu sistema.

Answer (score 2):

já tento div com id ?

```
<div class="" id="datatables1">
 conteudo 1
</div>
<div class="" id="datatables2">
 conteudo 2
</div>
```

entendeu ?

Comment: Tentei agora não foi.

Comment: use o exemplo acima, é quase igual o modo do meu http://prntscr.com/i29dtu

Comment: cara agora que entendi que tem que ativar no script por isso não tava pegando, só marquei a resposta do outro amigo porque estava mais completo, mais saquei pela sua.

Comment: Normal :v agradeço se me tentar ajudar, ou conhecer alguém fera em php para me ajudar no meu poster :P https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269993/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-exec-chama-programa-em-segundo-plano?noredirect=1#comment552952_269993